# CRM2011 FetchXML Reports for CRM with Office 365 Authentication

Tags: crm, office365, fetchxml

Ladies and gentlemen,

Has anyone done that? I have a **FetchXML** report that works fine in a regular on-line CRM2011, but it doesn’t work in CRM2011 with Office 365 authentication..

I'm pretty sure it is because of authentication.. Same thing that happens with SWTools.

Please help!)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used reports with Office 365 authentication but I have used the SDK. You don't need a device ID as with CRM Online; simply a username and a password, and your authentication method is online federation.

Hopefully, this is a hint in the right direction.